# Error in running the request in parallel in loop and get all request after completion and run the code different part of code in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am running multiple request in parallel and need to get output after all request is completed using promise.The Code is mentioned below.But getting error.

```
await get_url();
        ^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
      at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
      at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
```

-

```
const request = require('request');
console.log("---------Start script---------------");

var promises = [];
var sub = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < sub; i++) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        request("https://xxxxxx/", function(error, response, body) {
        //console.log("::::::body:::"+body);
        if (error) reject(error);
        resolve(body)
    })));
}

await Promise.all(promises)
      .then(function([first, second]) {
          console.log("===================");
          console.log("==================="+typeof(first));
          var k= JSON.parse(first);
          console.log("Name    :---->"+k.name);
});

//now run the below code after the above code has completed executing
//code to check if name start with letter 'S'

How to solve the error
```

Comment: `But getting error.` What error?

Answer (score 1):

**await** can't be used outside of an **async** function. You can wrap your **Promise.all** into async IIFE so that you can use await inside.

```
(async () => {
  await Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function ([first, second]) {
      console.log("===================");
      console.log("===================" + typeof (first));
      var k = JSON.parse(first);
      console.log("Name    :---->" + k.name);
    });
})()
```